# How to Receive List JSON at POST Filtering Errors

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, model-view-controller

I'am receiving **an array list of objects called Incidents**.

But when I receive any object on that list that doesn't meet the requirements to be inserted at my DB, **it simply ignore the entire list** and returns error 500.

I would like to know how to manage this, in a way that only the Incidents that have error are not inserted.

And if possible how can I know which ones have error and which error it is.

Here is my actual code, **I'm using Spring REST.**

At Incident DAO:

```
@Transactional
    public List<Incident> createIncident(List<Incident> incident) {
        for (int i = 0; i < incident.size(); i++) {
            try {
                em.persist(incident.get(i));
            } finally {

            }
        }
        return incident;
    }
```

At IncidentController:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public @ResponseBody List<Incident> create(@RequestBody List<Incident> incident) {
        return incidentDao.createIncident(incident);
    }
```

This is my latest try. I did an try to just ignore the ones that ends in an error but that just did the same I said before.

Thanks for any help, I'am new to Java and REST.

**EDIT: Latest try update**
Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public @ResponseBody List<Incident> create(@RequestBody List<Incident> incident) {
        if (incident != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < incident.size(); i++) {
                incidentDao.createIncident(incident.get(i));
            }
        }
        return incident;
    }
```

DAO:

```
@Transactional
    public boolean createIncident(Incident incident) {
         try{
             em.persist(incident);
             return true;
        }
          catch(Exception e){
             return false;
          }
    }
```

What I understood so far is that, my webservice function is treating this as an unique transaction so when one Incident from the list cannot commit, it's entire transaction rollback.

**EDIT(2): Solution found, but I guess it's not the ideal one, if someone finds another way more direct, I'll be happy!**

I had to create an Method on my composite primary key class, to set and get the arguments and created a search.

So, if this search returns something besides null it doesn't even try to add, if this returns null, that means that my 2 PK's are not found in my table, so the incident can be added(it added another search before each insert which is dumb, but I don't know another way right now).

```
  public Incident getIncidentByIDandDate(String incidentID, String date) {
//here comes the PK's class with the info I'm searching setted
                IncidentPK PK = new IncidentPK();
                PK.setIncidentID(incidentID);
                PK.setdate(date);

                Incident incident = em.find(Incident.class, PK);
                return incident;    
        } //if returns null means that no incident with this info's were found
```

**Thanks! Hope this helps someone else if they doesn't find another solution.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, but I guess it's not the ideal one, if someone finds another way more direct, I'll be happy!

I had to create an Method on my composite primary key class, to set and get the arguments and created a search.

So, if this search returns something besides null it doesn't even try to add, if this returns null, that means that my 2 PK's are not found in my table, so the incident can be added(it added another search before each insert which is dumb, but I don't know another way right now).

```
  public Incident getIncidentByIDandDate(String incidentID, String date) {
//here comes the PK's class with the info I'm searching setted
                IncidentPK PK = new IncidentPK();
                PK.setIncidentID(incidentID);
                PK.setdate(date);

                Incident incident = em.find(Incident.class, PK);
                return incident;    
        } //if returns null means that no incident with this info's were found
```

Thanks! Hope this helps someone else if they doesn't find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can have the loop in the controller.
So the code could look something like that

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public @ResponseBody List<Incident> create(@RequestBody List<Incident> incident) {
       if (incident!=null){
         for (int i = 0; i < incident.size(); i++) {
             boolean res = incidentDao.createIncident(incident.get(i));
           }
         }

       }
    }
```

and createIncident could return boolean (true if successfully inserted or false if something went wrong)

```
@Transactional
    public boolean createIncident(Incident incident) {
        try{
                em.persist(incident);
                return true;
           }
         catch(Exception e){
            e.print
            return false;
         }


    }
```

For every row, you would know if it was successfully being inserted into the database
If you want to know the error you could have print stack trace in the catch block
e.printStackTrace or if you want you can return the message of the exception in the function ie e.getMessage() and the function should return string instead of boolean

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives me the same error,

I changed some things like the return is needed at the controller and incident.get(i) must be passed(on the boolean res line.

And at the @transactional, it must receive a single incident right? because the loop is in the first function.

Thanks for your try!

Comment: Yes, I have changed the code slightly. Yes it should receive a single incident. So, what is the error?An error is not thrown at each createIncident?

Comment: It still doesn't add the entire list if one gives any error at persist.

So it just ignores the try I guess.

My test were, add 2 incidents, then add 1 incident with the same arguments(wrong ones) and 2 new after and before this incident.

Nothing has been added.

Comment: If you try all the incidents to be correct, is this saved in the database?

Comment: Yes, it is added correctly. Made that tests to ensure that the previous code's were working.

Comment: Added new Edits, maybe it will help to find an alternative idea, I was looking at Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW but it doesn't continue if it finds an error, just adds the ones before.